# Some Word documents are not opening with LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, word-documents

I have several of documents in Microsoft Word 2003 or later format. Few of them are opening using LibreOffice and few of them don't. They just open and immediately get closed. I tried changing their extensions to `.wpd` and `.odt`, but no luck.

My system is dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10. I SFTPed a folder from remote drive to Ubuntu, which contained lots of Word documents. Then unzipped in the local folder. It's less likely if any mis-formatting would have happened during FTPing.

I am open to other Libre equivalent app which can open Word.

Comment: Can you open them in another Ubuntu system with LibreOffice?

Comment: @iKrshnan, I don't know. Those are confidential docs, so can't share them also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should report a bug on `libreoffice` then.

Please check `/var/crash` folder to see if you have some `.crash` files generated. 
If there is some - follow the steps at [Enabling apport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport#How_to_enable_apport) and report a bug. 
If you don't - use `ubuntu-bug libreoffice` command to file a new bug. See [Reporting Bugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#How_to_report_bugs) for more information about bug reporting.

Don't forget to attach the files which cannot be opened.

Answer (score 0):

Install Abiword from the repos and try opening the dox in that. If successful, resave them under a different filename: strange but true, Libreoffice may be perfectly able to handle them then.  Let us know how things pan out.  Good luck!